# Google Datastore projection query on array of complex objects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have a simple Datastore kind having the following properties:

- id (long)
- createdAt (timestamp)
- userId (string)
- metrics (array of complex objects)

  - type of metric
  - value of metric

Each stored row in the Datastore might have a different amount of metrics as well as different types of metrics.

I have a very specific requirement to query the latest metrics of a user. The problem here is that different rows have different metrics so I can't just take the most recent row, I need to look into metrics array to retrieve all the data.

I decided to use projection queries. My idea was to create a projection based on the following properties: `metrics.type`, `metrics.value` and use distinct on `metrics.type` and adding order by `createdAt` desc.

For a better explanation, a simple example of rows from the Datastore:

```
1. { "id": 111, "createdAt": "2019-01-01 00:00", "userId" : "user-123", [{ "type" : "metric1", "value" : 123 }, { "type" : "metric2", "value" : 345 }] }
2. { "id": 222, "createdAt": "2019-01-02 00:00", "userId" : "user-123", [{ "type" : "metric3", "value" : 567 }, { "type" : "metric4", "value" : 789 }] }
```

I expected a projection query with distinct on `metrics.type` filter to return the following results:

```
1. "metric1", 123
2. "metric2", 345
3. "metric3", 567
4. "metric4", 789
```

but actually what query returns is:

```
1. "metric1", 123
2. "metric2", 123
3. "metric3", 123
4. "metric4", 123
```

So all metrics have the same value (which is incorrect). Basically it happens because of an exploded index - Datastore thinks I have 2 arrays but indeed it's a single array

Is there any way to make projection query to return what I expect instead of exploding the index? If not, how can I rebuild what I have so it meets my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Datastore documentation specifically warns your exact issue.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projections_and_array-valued_properties

One option to solve this is to combine both the type and value. So, have a property called "metric" that will have values like "metric1:123", "metric2:345". Then you will be projecting a single array-valued property.

Comment: In this case, I won't be able to retrieve the unique result for each metric